# Universal agent is not diplayed on Agent type dropdown on qtest automation agent

Tags: testing, automation, protractor, qtest

I'm trying to integrate an automation script written in protractor with test management tool qtest. While trying to integrate it needs an agent type, and the agent type should be Universal Agent. But the drop down didn't display universal agent as an option. What did I miss? Here I attached the gif file

Comment: the question is missing details

Answer (score 0):

After so many researches, I found the solution. My permission is denied for Launch functionality on the qtest. After I got that permission "Universal Agent" is displayed on the dropdown.